# App crashes with malloc: *** mmap(size=2147483648) failed (error code=12)

Tags: ios, c, memory-management, audio-streaming, avqueueplayer

I am creating a `AVQueuePlayer` object by adding AVPlayerItems. All player items points to different audio URL and player should play as soon as it buffers.

As I start the app in simulator, I get very strange issue with memory. The console says

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=2147483648) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and stack trace points some where internal in the framework. It juts points at function `#0 MP3AudioStream::GeneratePackets(AudioFileStreamContinuation&) ()`

I am not able to understand what is the issue.

Even adding breakpoint in `malloc_error_break`, doesn't giving any info.

Can some one help me in fixing the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

errno code 12 means out of memory.

Check the size parameter that is passed to malloc - it is invalid. The size value of -1 signed (2147483648 unsigned)  explains the out of memory error.

Comment: OK thanks, I will debug once again using instruments to catch this.